# Visual Studio でのライブラリファイルのパスの書き方

Tags: html, visual-studio, nuget

Visual Studio 2019 になって、NuGet で取得したライブラリの保存方法が変わり、プロジェクト毎ではなく、`C:\Users\[ユーザー名]\.nuget\packages` に一括して保存されるようになりました。
それは歓迎なのですが、.net MVC での View の *.cshtml ファイルで .css や .js のファイルへのパスをどのように書けば良いのでしょうか?

自動生成された `Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml` では以下のようになっていますが、実際の保存場所は `(略).nuget\packages\bootstrap\4.5.0\content\Content` であり、なぜ `"~lib/[ライブラリ名]/dist"` と書けば良いのかが分かりません。

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>        
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

ご指導ください。

Comment: この記事あたりかも。 [Adding packages with PackageReference doesn't add content files to ASP.NET project](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/72227/adding-packages-with-packagereference-doesnt-add-c.html) 開発環境でのフォルダ位置では無く、WebサイトとしてDeployされた結果のフォルダ構成を書いておく、ような感じでは？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。リンク先を良く読んでみます。きちんと理解するまでは次のように internet から取得するように書いておくのが無難なようです。　<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"

Answer (score 0):

実際にやって見て解決しました。　先ず、Visual Studio 2019 では　NuGet が取得した javascript 関連のライブラリと View の .cshtml ファイルが参照するライブラリは別物となります。

Visual Studio のソリューションエクスプローラー に wwwroot というディレクトリがあり、ここに css, js, lib というフォルダーがあり、ここが .cshtml から参照されるフォルダーとなります。　従って、jquery.js などはここの js または lib のフォルダーに置きます。
質問に書いた "~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" という記述は、この wwwroot を起点としたファイルの記述でした。
ここにライブラリを置くには、wwwroot を右クリックし、メニューの「追加 / クライアント側のライブラリ」という機能である程度自動的にできるが比較的単純な機能です。libman という機能のようです。

サマリ -
Visual Studio 2019 では、クライアント側のライブラリの管理は　nuget のライブラリ管理と別物である。　クライアント側でだけ使うライブラリを nuget でインストールしても意味はない。
クライアント側のライブラリは、ほぼ手動で管理する必要がある。 (libman という簡単なツールはある。)
.csmhtl ページからの参照は wwwroot を起点に、　"~/css/... " というように書く。